# Change order of evaluation in Plot[] nested with NDSolve[]

Tags: plotting, evaluation, symbolic

I noticed that in `Plot` the function is evaluated at each sample point

```
Plot[func@x,{x,rStart1,rEnd1}]
```

which is fine for a regular function. If I substitute the function with an NDSolve, the problem is that at every sample point the NDSolve is evaluated so it is time consuming.

```
Plot[NDSolve[(*diff equation*)][[1]]@x,{x,rStart1,rEnd1}]
```

I find a workaround to NDSolve only once, and pass it to the `Plot[]`.

```
NDSolve[(*diff equation*)][[1]] //Plot[#@x, {x, rStart1, rEnd1}] &
```

I just wonder if there is a better way to do it, for example to `Hold/Release` or some magical trick to force it only being evaluated once.

Comment: possibly of interest: [Plotting the sum of curves without recalculation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114790/34893).

Comment: Indeed it is interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve

Answer (score 2):

Two alternatives that would evaluate only once.

Let's verify that by using a counter

```
counter = 0;
Dynamic[counter]
```

### `With`

```
With[
 {
  func = NDSolve[
     counter += 1;
     {y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}
     , y
     , {x, 0, 30}
     ][[1, 1, 2]]
  },
 Plot[
  func[x]
  , {x, 0, 30}
  , PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

### `Evaluate`

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  y[x] /. NDSolve[
    counter += 1;
    {y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}
    , y
    , {x, 0, 30}
    ]]
 , {x, 0, 30}
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way in V9+ is

```
ListLinePlot@ NDSolve[(*ode for y[x]*), y, x]
```

Example from @rhermans:

```
ListLinePlot@ 
 NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]